# svnsync not working properly

Tags: svn, version-control, synchronization, svnsync

I want to sync an SVN repository from one server to another server. I used `svnsync`, but when I checkout the mirrored SVN repo, it's empty. All of the versioned files are not in sync, only the revision number.

This is what I did:

**On the mirror server**

- create the SVN repo

  `svnadmin create XXX`
- modify hooks/add pre-revprop-change

  `#!/bin/sh

  exit 0`

**On the main server**

- modify hooks/ add post-commit

`svnsync sync --non-interactive svn://192.168.1.98/ubetween_backup1 --username an --password an`

- `svnsync init svn://192.168.1.98/XXX_backup1 svn://192.168.1.29/XXX`
- `svnsync sync svn://192.168.1.98/XXX_backup1 --username an --password an`

Then I do the regular update/checkout/commit, but **only the revision number has synced, not the files**.

What did I do wrong?